# Rails fields_for form not showing up, nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created an simple rails project. All worked fine until I tried to add a new model `Paintings` that `belongs_to` treatment and an `Patient` that `has_many` Paintings through Treatment. So somehow the nested form I created does not show up, I believe it has to do with the controller! Thanks, and greetings from Germany!

Treatments controller:

```
class TreatmentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.create(params[:treatment])
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
  end

  def destroy
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.find(params[:id])
    @treatment.destroy
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)  
  end
end
```

And the form for treatments with `nested fields_for` that doesn't show up:

```
<%= form_for([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => "30", :rows => "10" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :typ %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :paintings do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :name, 'Tag:' %>
      <%= ff.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE:**

Show Site:

```
<% @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %></td>
    <td><%= treatment.content %></td>
    <td><%= treatment.day %></td>
    <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

Comment: try f.fields_for :paintings, Painting.new do |m|. Also, can u post the models code and the controller code in more details?

Comment: haha your the best!! I tried it two days and now you made it with only one litlle bite add of code! Please move your comment to a answer so that i can set it to the right answer!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Please try

```
= f.fields_for :paintings, Painting.new do |p|
```

Comment: Sorry but one more thing, how can i show the name of the image up?

Comment: i really dont have any idea about the model relationships or the fields. can u pls add them?

Comment: I mean in the same view i added to my post in the update! SO that ther is another <td> with the name of the image

Comment: u cant display a painting name for a newly built painting object unless u have specified some default value. in the 'form' u cant cause the object fields hold 'nil' value unless u have specified a default value. in the updated view where u have listed the treatments, u can show the names of all the paintings for a particular treatment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31964/discussion-between-surase-prasad-and-em-sta)

Answer (score 16):

Even the question is quite old, but you are missing the `new` that is crucial to this question. The methods `destroy` and `create` doesn't have anything with this issue. If you have a `new` method, which looks something like this:

```
class TreatmentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @patient = Patient.new
  end
end
```

Then the solution would be do modify the `new` method to "build" the `paintings`  like this:

```
class TreatmentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @patient = Patient.new
    @patient.paintings.build
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, but these demo codes has no `.build` action :-(

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/blob/master/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb#L26

Comment: @zx1986 What do you mean by `they don't have build action`? I mean it shouldn't have the build action. The `build` is just a method to for the object.

Answer (score 11):

Try doing following in new action in controller

```
@patient.treatments.build
```

Check out build_association part http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

You should also read about nested attributes.
Use those for reference
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: this is a wrong syntax. try `@patient.treatments.build`

Answer (score 9):

Dumb error, but I was using:

```
<% f.fields_for :partner do |fp| %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= f.fields_for :partner do |fp| %>
```

Comment: I have made the same mistake in `haml` file and wondering what the heck is wrong with my form for like 30 minutes... Oh my God...
I use `- f.fields_for :partner do |fp|` instead of `= f.fields_for :partner do |fp|`

Comment: Man, your post saved my life. I wasted EIGHT HOURS of my life and started losing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

is case you have an association where it is optional:

in the controller:

```
@associated_model = @model.associated_model || @model.build_associated_model
```

in the view:

```
<%= form.fields_for :associated_model do |am| %>
```