# Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

How can I upload multiple images from a file selection window using Rails 4 and CarrierWave? I have a `post_controller` and `post_attachments` model. How can I do this?

Can someone provide an example? Is there a simple approach to this?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

> **This is solution to upload multiple images using carrierwave in rails 4 from scratch**
>
> **Or you can find working demo :
>   [Multiple Attachment Rails 4](https://github.com/savanr/rails-carrierwave-multiple-attachment)**

**To do just follow these steps.**

```
rails new multiple_image_upload_carrierwave
```

**In gem file**

```
gem 'carrierwave'
bundle install
rails generate uploader Avatar
```

**Create post scaffold**

```
rails generate scaffold post title:string
```

**Create post_attachment scaffold**

```
rails generate scaffold post_attachment post_id:integer avatar:string

rake db:migrate
```

**In post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :post_attachments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments
end
```

**In post_attachment.rb**

```
class PostAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
   belongs_to :post
end
```

**In post_controller.rb**

```
def show
   @post_attachments = @post.post_attachments.all
end

def new
   @post = Post.new
   @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
end

def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
       params[:post_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
          @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:avatar => a)
       end
       format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
     end
   end
 end

 private
   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :avatar])
   end
```

**In views/posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </div>

   <%= f.fields_for :post_attachments do |p| %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= p.label :avatar %><br>
       <%= p.file_field :avatar, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[avatar][]" %>
     </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

To edit an attachment and list of attachment for any post.
**In views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<% @post_attachments.each do |p| %>
  <%= image_tag p.avatar_url %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Attachment", edit_post_attachment_path(p) %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Update form to edit an attachment **views/post_attachments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= image_tag @post_attachment.avatar %>
<%= form_for(@post_attachment) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Modify update method in **post_attachment_controller.rb**

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post_attachment.update(post_attachment_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @post_attachment.post, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully updated.' }
    end 
  end
end
```

In rails 3 no need to define strong parameters and as you can define attribute_accessible in both the model and accept_nested_attribute to post model because attribute accessible is deprecated in rails 4.

For edit an attachment we cant modify all the attachments at a time. so we will replace attachment one by one, or you can modify as per your rule, Here I just show you how to update any attachment.

Comment: in the show action of the post controller i think you've forgot @post =Post.find(params[:id])

Comment: Yes thanks, but In rails 4 by default there is one method called "set_post" when you create scaffold. it finds parameter for show, edit, update method.

Comment: @SSR Why you looping through each post attachments in `create` action? Rails and carrierwave are smart enough to save collections automatically.

Comment: It's not possible to create a Post then go back and change the image? @SSR

Comment: @Chris: Means you want to create a post first and then attach a Image?

Comment: @hawk : Yea we can do so. but when you cant find nested attributes params, then you can do so.

Comment: @SSR :I have used the code, in my index method in post_controller  `code`@posts = Posts.all
@post_attachment = @posts.post_attachments.all`code`
I have undefined method post_attachments for <Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa6087482a8>

Comment: This works great on a new post but does not look very good on an edit. Anyway to avoid showing all attachments in the edit form?

Comment: @Jepzen : Will update my ans with edit view very soon. Actually I missed that part. I didn't work on that yet but I will do now.

Comment: Would love to see edit (especially handling `:_destroy` part)

Comment: I am not getting the above answer you have posted for edit, how we will edit multiple files if we are using accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Comment: @DeeptiKakade : You can add multiple items at a time but can't change or update multiple items at time. because how you define that which item will replace with existing one. so you can only edit a single item.

Comment: This has been very helpful! Do you know how to use cache to sort-of save the files to the uploaded? I've been having trouble using the cache feature for multiple file uploads.

Comment: @SSR - Your answer is very helpful. Could you please update your answer with edit action too.

Comment: Why do you need to include the post_attachments in the post_params as these are not being mass assigned as a normal nested attribute is? These are being manually added within the create action referencing the params hash directly. I removed the post_attachments from the strong params and it still works.

Comment: Upon further testing it doesn't work with the nested item removed from the strong params.

Comment: Hi @SSR, if I want just ONE (maybe the first) image to show on the index page while all images showing on the show, what do I need to do on the index page to just have the first image showing (not every image)

Comment: Does anyone know how to make the images persist in a form that has been submitted and failed due to validation errors? There's documentation for this in the carrierwave gem but only for individual files, and I can't get it working for this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: In the create controller shouldn't it be `params[:post][:post_attachments]['avatar'].each`?  `params[:post_attachments]` is nil

Comment: When I add validations to the post_attachment model, they do not prevent the post model from saving. Instead the post is saved, and then the ActiveRecord invalid error is thrown for the attachment model only. I think this is because of the create! method. but using create instead just fails silently. Any idea how to have the validation happen on the post reach into the attachments?

Comment: Since this is making a gallery, is there a way to make this work with carrierwave versions i.e. generating and using thumbnails

Answer (score 32):

If we take a look at CarrierWave's documentation, this is actually very easy now.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md#multiple-file-uploads

I will use Product as the model I want to add the pictures, as an example.

1. Get the master branch Carrierwave and add it to your Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'carrierwave', github:'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
   ```
2. Create a column in the intended model to host an array of images:

   ```
   rails generate migration AddPicturesToProducts pictures:json
   ```
3. Run the migration

   ```
   bundle exec rake db:migrate
   ```
4. Add pictures to model Product

   ```
   app/models/product.rb

   class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :name, presence: true
     mount_uploaders :pictures, PictureUploader
   end
   ```
5. Add pictures to strong params in ProductsController

   ```
   app/controllers/products_controller.rb

   def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(:name, pictures: [])
   end
   ```
6. Allow your form to accept multiple pictures

   ```
   app/views/products/new.html.erb

   # notice 'html: { multipart: true }'
   <%= form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>

     # notice 'multiple: true'
     <%= f.label :pictures %>
     <%= f.file_field :pictures, multiple: true, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png" %>

     <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
   <% end %>
   ```
7. In your views, you can reference the images parsing the pictures array:

   ```
   @product.pictures[1].url
   ```

If you choose several images from a folder, the order will be the exact order you are taking them from top to bottom.

Comment: CarrierWave's solution to this problem makes me cringe. It involves putting all the references to the files into one field in an array! It certainly wouldn't be considered the "rails way". What if you then want to remove some, or add extra files to the post? I'm not saying it wouldn't be possible, I'm just saying it would be ugly. A join table is a much better idea.

Comment: I couldn't agree more Toby. Would you be so kind to provide that solution?

Comment: That solutions is already provided by SSR. Another model is put in place to hold the uploaded file, then the thing that needs many files uploaded relates in a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship with that other model. (the join table I mentioned in my earlier comment would be in the case of a many-to-many relationship)

Comment: Thanks @Toby1Kenobi, I was wondering how the column array method would account for image versions (I don't see how it can). Your strategy is doable.

Comment: I have implemented this feature of Carrierwave with Rails 5.x.x, https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md#multiple-file-uploads

But I am not able to run it successfully, and it is generating error, `UndefinedConversionError ("\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)`

For SSR solution, it works fine with Rails 4.x.x, but I am facing challenges (with Rails 5.x.x.) 
i.e. its storing `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` in database instead filename. Its also not storing  files in public folders for given path in uploader.

Comment: Putting multiple images of an entity inside one JSON/text field makes it also impossible to assign `title` and `alt` attributes for those images, unless it is possible to do so using nested JSON. Any idea?

Comment: Multiple file upload has several issues with carrierwave with  mount_uploaders :pictures, PictureUploader

Answer (score 8):

Some minor additions to the **SSR** answer:

**accepts_nested_attributes_for** does not require you to change the parent object's controller. So if to correct

```
name: "post_attachments[avatar][]"
```

to

```
name: "post[post_attachments_attributes][][avatar]"
```

then all these controller changes like these become redundant:

```
params[:post_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
  @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:avatar => a)
end
```

Also you should add `PostAttachment.new` to the parent object form:

**In views/posts/_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= f.fields_for :post_attachments, PostAttachment.new do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :avatar %><br>
      <%= ff.file_field :avatar, :multiple => true, name: "post[post_attachments_attributes][][avatar]" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This would make redundant this change in the parent's controller:

```
@post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
```

For more info see [Rails fields_for form not showing up, nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175850/rails-fields-for-form-not-showing-up-nested-form)

If you use Rails 5, then change `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default` value from `true` to `false` (in config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb) due to a bug inside **accepts_nested_attributes_for** (otherwise **accepts_nested_attributes_for** won't generally work under Rails 5).

**EDIT 1:**

To add about **destroy**:

**In models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**In views/posts/_form.html.erb**

```
 <% f.object.post_attachments.each do |post_attachment| %>
    <% if post_attachment.id %>

      <%

      post_attachments_delete_params =
      {
      post:
        {              
          post_attachments_attributes: { id: post_attachment.id, _destroy: true }
        }
      }

      %>

      <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(f.object.id, post_attachments_delete_params), method: :patch, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

      <br><br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This way you simply **do not need** to have a child object's controller at all! I mean no any `PostAttachmentsController` is needed anymore. As for parent object's controller (`PostController`), you also *almost* don't change it - the only thing you change in there is the list of the whitelisted params (to include the child object-related params) like this:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, 
    post_attachments_attributes: ["avatar", "@original_filename", "@content_type", "@headers", "_destroy", "id"])
end
```

That's why the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is so amazing.

Comment: Those are actually major additions to @SSR answer, not minor :) accept_nested_attributes_for is quite something. Indeed there's no need for a child controller at all. By following your approach, the only thing I'm unable to do is to display form error messages for the child when something goes wrong with the upload.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I got the upload working, but I am wondering how I could add additional attributes to the post_attachments form field in views/posts/_form.html.erb? `<%= d.text_field :copyright, name: "album[diapos_attributes][][copyright]", class: 'form-field' %>` writes the copyright only to the last record and not to all of them.

Answer (score 6):

Also I figured out how to update the multiple file upload and I also refactored it a bit.  This code is mine but you get the drift.

```
def create
  @motherboard = Motherboard.new(motherboard_params)
  if @motherboard.save
    save_attachments if params[:motherboard_attachments]
    redirect_to @motherboard, notice: 'Motherboard was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end


def update
  update_attachments if params[:motherboard_attachments]
  if @motherboard.update(motherboard_params)
    redirect_to @motherboard, notice: 'Motherboard was successfully updated.'
  else
   render :edit
  end
end

private
def save_attachments
  params[:motherboard_attachments]['photo'].each do |photo|
    @motherboard_attachment = @motherboard.motherboard_attachments.create!(:photo => photo)
  end
end

 def update_attachments
   @motherboard.motherboard_attachments.each(&:destroy) if @motherboard.motherboard_attachments.present?
   params[:motherboard_attachments]['photo'].each do |photo|
     @motherboard_attachment = @motherboard.motherboard_attachments.create!(:photo => photo)
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. when you get time please update code at my gihub repo and do not forget to comment for each method so everyone can easily understand code.

Comment: I cloned the repos, will you give me permission to do a PR?

Comment: Yes sure. What is your github username

Comment: Have you had a chance to give me access?

Answer (score 2):

When using the association `@post.post_attachments` you do not need to set the `post_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my second refactor into the model:

1. Move private methods to model.
2. Replace @motherboard with self.

Controller:

```
def create
  @motherboard = Motherboard.new(motherboard_params)

  if @motherboard.save
    @motherboard.save_attachments(params) if params[:motherboard_attachments]
  redirect_to @motherboard, notice: 'Motherboard was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def update
  @motherboard.update_attachments(params) if params[:motherboard_attachments]
  if @motherboard.update(motherboard_params)
    redirect_to @motherboard, notice: 'Motherboard was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

In motherboard model:

```
def save_attachments(params)
  params[:motherboard_attachments]['photo'].each do |photo|
    self.motherboard_attachments.create!(:photo => photo)
  end
end

def update_attachments(params)
  self.motherboard_attachments.each(&:destroy) if self.motherboard_attachments.present?
  params[:motherboard_attachments]['photo'].each do |photo|
    self.motherboard_attachments.create!(:photo => photo)
  end
end
```