# Rails Carrierwave non-image file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, carrierwave

I am trying to upload attachments to my model using Carrierwave. I am following instructions from this post:

[Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave)

In the PostAttachment class, the instructions say add "mount_uploader:avatar, AvatarUploader" which suggests it is an image file. However, I want to upload files such as pdf, excel, word, ppt, etc... So what do I add to the model instead?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also have one model for uploading files (e.g FileUploader), you only need the attribute `type` to distinguish different file types/file extension

Comment: Any file can be uploaded unless its type is not validated in model.

Comment: @rails_id thank you would you be able to elaborate on how to do that?