# Best way to store many image frames in ActiveRecord with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading

I'm using Ruby On Rails 4 + ActiveRecord + CarrierWave to store images.
Now I have task - to store many image frames in each AR record for [SpriteSpin](http://spritespin.ginie.eu/) 360 views. I have trouble with traditional way to store images - SpriteSpin requires up to 34 image frames. I think it isn't best way to create 34 or more attributes, and upload each frame separately.
Maybe there is more correct way to upload and store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CarrierWave doesn't support `multiple` uploads. It's designed to associate a single file with a single field.

If you want multiple uploads, you need either multiple fields (each with a CarrierWave uploader), or multiple objects each with a single CarrierWave uploader field.

The `multiple` attribute is also unsupported, so if you use it, it's entirely up to you to get the parameters assigned properly.

Here are some references of multiple uploads via Carrierwave. I am not sure you like these tricks or not? But for your reference I found..

- [Multiple file upload with carrierwave, nested form and jquery file upload](https://u.osu.edu/hasnan.1/2014/03/30/rails-4-multiple-file-upload-with-carrierwave-nested-form-and-jquery-file-upload/)
- [Multiple file uploads with Ajax, Carrierwave, & Mongoid](https://github.com/huobazi/ajax-upload-with-carrierwave-mongoid)
- [Stack Overflow's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave#answer-21412174)

I hope this helps you somehow... Or wait for someone's answer who had done this before. I am big fan of and love to use **[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)**