# Rails Multiple image upload (paperclip, carrerwave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, carrierwave

is there any good tutorial for this solution with or without JS? I can't find any handy tutorial or example in internet. some tutors are very old, some not works. I can't believe that for such famous framework not recorded good tutorial for such common thing as multiply file uploading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a link you can find it here.
Actually it depends on your requirement how you are going to implement, and why not to using js?

[Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave/21412174#21412174)

You can perform same steps using paperclip.

You can also use fine-upload, http://docs.fineuploader.com/