# How to implement multiple file upload and how to download the files with same id as a zip using carrierwave rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

i am using [Carrierwave file upload](http://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave) for uploading and downloading the files.
my model:

```
class InvoiceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
  validates :invoice_number, :supplier_name, :attachment, presence: true    
  validates_uniqueness_of :invoice_number
end
```

attachment/uploader.rb:

```
 def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def filename
```

"#{model.invoice_number}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end

invoice_detail/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@invoice_detail , html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form' }) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :invoice_number, :class => 'control-label' %>
            <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :invoice_number, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supplier_name, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">

    <%= f.text_field :supplier_name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

     <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :attachment , :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.file_field :attachment, :class => 'file_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create Invoice Details", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= f.submit "cancel", :class => 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to cancel' } %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

The present code is working fine with single file upload. 
Now my requirement is to store multiple files (Multiple file upload) and when I click on download all the multiple files under same id has to be zipped and downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow the link [multiple upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave) for multiple uploads. 
And in order to download your files as a zip, one of the finest method is to use [rubyzip gem](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip).

Comment: Thanks . I got multiple upload and faced errors with download as a zip. The rubyzip gem works for me :)