# Unable to upload multiple images with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm having a problem uploading multiple images via Carrierwave and am not sure if it's a bug or user error (probably the latter). I'm doing everything in a rather standard way though (as per documentation) so it's weird that this doesn't work.

I have the following in my **Gemfile**:
`gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'`

my **image_uploader.rb**:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [590, 590]
  end
  version :featured do
    process :resize_to_fill => [390, 390]
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

My **article.rb** file:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader
end
```

I am letting the params pass from my controller with:

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :images, :body)
end
```

And the **_form.html.erb** partial uses:

```
<%= form_for @article, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :images %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %><br>
  <%= f.submit 'Update Article' %>
<% end %>
```

Oddly, when I upload two images, I am not seeing them passed into the article_params from the update method.

If I pry it, I can see that:

```
params.require(:article).permit(:images)
Unpermitted parameters: title, images, body
=> {}
```

Images seems to be unpermitted, even though I explicitly permit it...

Any clue as to what may be incorrect here?

Comment: Seems like you implemented multiple upload incorrectly. Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave). It explain how to implement multiple upload with Carrierwave.

Comment: @maxd I was working off the example on the official documentation: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads I wonder if that's not the correct way to do it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be:

```
params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, images: [])
```

If you take a look in pry on `images` param, its type is an Array:

```
> params[:article][:images].class
=> Array
```

From docs:

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:
>
> > ```
> > params.permit(id: [])
> > ```

Source: [4.5.1 Permitted Scalar Values](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Comment: Genius! Thanks so much for that. There's only one mistake: it should be `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, {images: []})` Images apparently needs to be wrapped around a hash.

Comment: @raqhqu any clue how I'd remove individual uploads via a checkbox? Using something like `<%= f.check_box :remove_images %>` will remove all the uploaded files.