# How to download multiple files of an id uploaded as a zip using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

i am using carrierwave for multiple file uploads.

My post model:

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :post_attachments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments
end
```

post_attachment.rb:

```
class PostAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
   belongs_to :post
end
```

posts_controller.rb:

```
def show
   @post_attachments = @post.post_attachments.all
end

def new
   @post = Post.new
   @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
end

def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
       params[:post_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
          @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :post_id => @post.id)
       end
       format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
     end
   end
 end

 private
   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :avatar])
   end
```

and my posts/_form is:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </div>

   <%= f.fields_for :post_attachments do |p| %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= p.label :avatar %><br>
       <%= p.file_field :avatar, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[avatar][]" %>
     </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Actually the above code is referred from [Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave).

Initially i have done single file upload using http://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave where I used to download the file. For this I used to write a method in my controller as:

```
 def download
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
            if params[:post_id].nil?
                redirect_to :back
            else
              begin
                post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
                attachment_file = File.join('public', post.attachment.url)
                if File.exists?(attachment_file)
                  send_file attachment_file, :disposition => 'attachment'
                else
                  redirect_to :back
                end
              rescue Exception => error
                redirect_to :back
              end
            end
        }
      end
  end
```

and in posts/index.html.erb:

```
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <%= link_to image_tag("download.png"), download_post_path(post.id) %>

        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

attachment_uploader.rb:

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

How can I download multiple files for a post_id as a zip with my code?

Comment: I don't think you can download multiple files from the exact same URL. You might want to generate a link for each file OR zip all the files into one and send it (not a good solution IMO : can take some time to generate the zip file)

Comment: @MrYoshiji : Is there anyway to zip all the files with same post id ?

Comment: There is, yes, but it will take some time to generate the Zip file : you click on the download link, the server gather all the files, generate a zip, and then send it to you. This operation can take several seconds, unless you create a complex "cache" system which would generate Zip files for each Post right after the files of a Post have been updated/changed/deleted/added. But that seems to be way too much in your case

Comment: @MrYoshiji - can you provide me any link or help me how to download as zip apart from creating "cache" system.