# Rails count number of all Carrierwave uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am working on a rails project, using Carrierwave for uploading files and images. I just need a way to count number of files uploaded to server via carrierwave. Something like `AvatarUploader.all.count` ?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `counter_cache` will help you?

Comment: @DavidKristianLaundav Nothing at all, I guess there must be a ruby based solution to this, like counting all the uploader directory images/files recursively!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Model A, make a has_many association to Model A_attachments that gets created for each attachment and simply count them by A_attachments.count.

For counting the number of models in record, you just need ModelName.count and that's it.

There's a really detailed explanation from a user named SSR 
in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/21412174

I don't want to copy and paste the answer because he really deserves an upvote for this.