# Carrierwave Multiple File Uploading - Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, carrierwave

I have a page which i can add attachments. I wanted to add multiple files during browsing so i added the :multiple => true method on my input, so it looks like this during this input:  f.has_many :attachments

```
f.input :file , :input_html => { :multiple => true }
```

For multiple attachments to be added / seen on the attachment panel i have this:

```
attachment=[]

(0..params[:kayako_client_ticket][:attachment].count-1).each do |f|
 attachment << {:filename => params[:kayako_client_ticket][:attachment]      
 [f].original_filename,:data => File.new(params[:kayako_client_ticket] 
 [:attachment][f].tempfile).read}
end unless params[:kayako_client_ticket][:attachment].blank?
```

In my model file, attachments are referenced like this:

```
has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
```

And if I add multiple files , i get this error :

```
You are not allowed to upload nil files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, xlsb, csv, txt, ppt, pptx, pps, ppsx, pdf, xpf
```

What do you recommend me to do in this situation?

PS: Thanks for your future answers.

Comment: More details to provide?

Comment: From the errors,Is your file type in the list of approved file types?

Comment: Yes , it is. I tried different filetypes which should be accepted.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave

Comment: Yes, I viewed that topic a couple of hours ago but it wasn't useful in this situation.

Comment: Can you post the output for this 
`params[:kayako_client_ticket][:attachment].count`

Comment: it's just a for loop. that's not the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103860/discussion-between-sureshprasanna70-and-rails-coder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely would help if you refactored your code some. Consider this

```
attachments = params[:kayako_client_ticket][:attachment]

unless attachments.empty?
  attachments.inject([]) do |array, attachment|
    array << {filename: attachment.original_filename, data: File.new(attachment.tempfile).read}
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi there. It wasn't either kayako or carrierwave.It was more vast problem, so we created a function during our page for the number of attachments(size of file and total number of files) whilst the page was updating. Thanks anyway !!