# add more files with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have implemented an upload file system with carrierwave on ruby on rails. Currently each user have a single file, how can I do to when the user upload a new file, to add instead of overwrite? Allowing this way the user to have many files (only uploading one at each time)

this is my user controller:

```
def update  #upload personal file
  files = current_user.personal_files
  files += params[:user][:personal_files]
  current_user.personal_files = files
  current_user.save

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      # copy_file   #make a copy of the uploaded file in public/files/data.xml for running in the bat file
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'File was sucessfully uploaded!' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }

    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

when I add a new file, it appears in the DB: [nil, "new_file"]. appears nil and overwrites the oldfile with the new.

and my view:

```
<%= form_for current_user, :method => :put, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <h4 class="h1-form">Submit your personal performance file in order to WebProcessPAIR analyse your performance problems</h4>
  <div class="field-wrap">
    <div class="input-group image-preview">
      <input type="text" class="form-control txt_color file_text log_placeholder" placeholder="Upload xml file" disabled="disabled">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-large btn-default  btn-file">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
          Browse
          <%= f.file_field :personal_files, accept: 'text/xml', multiple: true %>
        </span>
        <%= button_tag(:type => 'submit', :class => 'btn btn-info sbmt', :disabled => true) do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i> Upload
        <% end %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your controller method. You must have implemented multiple file upload as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227021/1684772)

```
files = upload.files # copy the old images
files << params[:upload][:file] # add new file to the files
upload.files = files # assign back
upload.save
```

Comment: i cant do this without multiple upload at each time ?

Comment: If your database is setup with provision for only one file, you cannot expect it to store multiple files.

Comment: but im saying, just the part with the multiple: true

Comment: `multipart: true` is required anyways. Not `multiple: true`. `multipart: true` enables the form with file uploading capability.

Comment: it continues to overwrite :/

Comment: with += added nil to the DB, and with << says this `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: You need to modify `params[:upload][:file]` with whatever file param you have.

Comment: i have like this `params[:user][:personal_files]`

Comment: Can you try removing `multiple: true` from `<%= f.file_field :personal_files, accept: 'text/xml', multiple: true %>`?

Comment: i tried. it gives me `no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into Array`

Comment: As I have updated in the answer, change `files += params[:user][:personal_files]` to `current_user.personal_files << params[:user][:personal_files]`

Comment: and if i put `params[:user][:personal_files].path` in the controller it gives `no implicit conversion of String into Array`

Comment: `undefined method remove_previously_stored_files_after_update' `

Comment: Make sure you have `gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'` in `Gemfile` and `bundle install`

Comment: Not sure about the issue. I hope you can Google it around.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Try this `multiple: true` in the form_for . Hope this would help you.