# Rails, uploading multiple images with carrierwave, but json not supported by my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, carrierwave

I am trying to use Carrierwave with multiple image uploads.
After following the carrierwave guide on github I do:

```
rails g migration add_images_to_areas images:json
rake db:migrate
```

But seeing on my schema, my areas table does not show up, instead I get:

```
# Could not dump table "areas" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'json' for column 'images'
```

What should I do now? Should I use another type instead of json, but what?

Sorry if this is an amateur question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure as to what was going wrong here, The github tutorial of Carrierwave was suggesting **:json**, but you don't have to do so.

Everything went fine after I just followed the guide for multiple image upload with Carrierwave here: [Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave)

Answer (score 2):

Databases by default don't support arrays, hashes and so on.

In order to do it, you can serialize it adding this code to your model:

```
class Name_class < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :column_name, JSON
end
```

And change the migration field :

```
add_column :user_preferences, :text
```

This will insert the info as `Text` into the database and, when you retrieve it , it will be `JSON`.

More info about `serialization` here [RailsGuides#Serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Databases support arrays or json, with some extensions.

Comment: I didn't know that . I always use serialize when i need a json or array field in the database.   
Thank you for the info though,

Comment: @RubenBarbosa thank for the tip, I will try it and get right back at you.

Comment: @Зелёный Is there an easy way for mysql to support json? I know Postgres can support it, should I change to that?

Comment: Hollywar detected, choise by yourself. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: @RubenBarbosa I tried what you said but it does not work. The :images attribute is always nil.
In my controller I have 
`params.require(:area).permit(:id,  {images: []})`

 How do you handle that in your controller?

Comment: Can you put the code of your controller?, the action when you save it in the database. I think the problem is there.

Comment: About the permit stuff, that should be okay. It's the right syntax and it should be working. It could be the `create` action ?

Comment: @RubenBarbosa I actually followed a the answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave and made it work. Also it seems like it has to be `add_column :user_preferences, :string`

Comment: Text and String only differ in the capacity of the field , but i'm glad you solve your problem. Answer your own question and mark it as Answered, it will be of help for others.

Comment: @RubenBarbosa I did, thanks for trying to help anyway!