# Schema.rb display Could not dump table "progresses" because of following NoMethodError # undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

---

I am trying to add a multiple image uploader with **Carrierwave** [following the documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to my app.

Normally my schema.rb looks like this

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160814232416) do

   create_table "progresses", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "title"
     t.string   "date"
     t.text     "content"
     t.datetime "created_at", null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end
  end
```

And when I run :

`rails g migration add_images_to_progresses images:json`
and
`rake db:migrate`

My schema change and display that weird thing....
Is it a problem with Sqlite3 or Pg? What should I do ?

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160815005123) do

  # Could not dump table "progresses" because of following NoMethodError
  #undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the same code for both SQLite and PostgreSql. In SQLite there is no datatype "JSON" available, and so it throws an error. When I tried the same in PostgreSQL, it worked.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160815070637) do 
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  create_table "progresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "date"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.json     "images"
  end

end
```

If you want to use the SQLite then you will have to generate a string from your JSON and then save that string in your database as a regular string.

I prefer to use PostgreSQL, which supports JSON datatype.