# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass but the article is published

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, simple-form

I have created a form in order to create articles, it has fields for title,  date, content, main image, and a special field for the multiple upload. Images are uploaded with Carrierwave.

I have two differents models and controllers that work with this form. **progress** and **progress_attachments**.

As I want to attach multiple images in order to create a photos gallery I have created this other controller **progress_attachment**  *I followed [SSR explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave)*

When I submit my form, I have this error

```
NoMethodError in ProgressesController#create
    undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Even though the article is published... (I can find it in rails console, and If I go back to the show)

I beleive that this `undefined method []`comes from my create method in the the progress controller, but I am missing something and I don't understand what...??

**progresses_controller.rb**

```
class ProgressesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @progresses = Progress.all
  end

  def show
    @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])
    @progress_attachments = @progress.progress_attachments.all
  end

  def new
     @progress = Progress.new
     @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.build
  end

  def create
     @progress = Progress.new(progress_params)

     respond_to do |format|
       if @progress.save
         params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
            @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.create!(:image => a)
         end
         format.html { redirect_to progresses_path, notice: 'Progress was successfully created.' }
       else
         format.html { render action: 'new' }
       end
     end
   end

   def update
     respond_to do |format|
       if @progress.update(article_params)
         format.html { redirect_to @progress, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @progress }
       else
         format.html { render :edit }
         format.json { render json: @progress.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end

   def destroy
     @progress.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
     end
   end
   private
     def progress_params
        params.require(:progress).permit(:title, :content, :date, :main_image, progress_attachments_attributes: [:id, :progress_id, :image])
     end

end
```

**progress_attachments_controller.rb**

```
class ProgressAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_progress_attachment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @progress_attachments = ProgressAttachment.all
  end

  def new
    @progress_attachment = ProgressAttachment.new
  end

  def create
    @progress_attachment = ProgressAttachment.new(progress_attachment_params)
    @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.build
    respond_to do |format|
      if @progress_attachment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @progress_attachment, notice: 'Progress attachment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @progress_attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @progress_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @progress_attachment.update(progress_attachment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @progress_attachment, notice: 'Progress attachment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @progress_attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @progress_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @progress_attachment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to progress_attachments_url, notice: 'Progress attachment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_progress_attachment
      @progress_attachment = ProgressAttachment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def progress_attachment_params
      params.require(:progress_attachment).permit(:progress_id, :image)
    end
end
```

**the form in views/progresses/new.html.slim**

```
 = simple_form_for(@progress, html: { multipart: true} ) do |f|
   =f.input :title
   =f.input :date
   =f.input :content
   =f.input :main_image
   =f.simple_fields_for :progress_attachments do |f|
     =f.input_field :image, multiple: true, name: "progress_attachments_attributes[:image][]"
   =f.button :submit
```

**I have edited the form since I have solved the problem of multiple uploads**

**models/progress_attachment.rb**

```
class ProgressAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :progress
  validates :image, presence: true
end
```

**models/progress.rb**

```
class Progress < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope ->{order(created_at: :DESC)}
  mount_uploader :main_image, MainImageUploader
  has_many :progress_attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :progress_attachments

  validates :main_image,   presence: true
  validates :title,   presence: true
  validates :content,  presence: true
  validates :date,    presence: true
end
```

## EDIT

this is my pry on my actual controller.

```
Started POST "/progresses" for ::1 at 2016-09-02 01:37:49 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ProgressesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KdZkIvo+lbmE8JPlMNOOFc2grNG6w9u4kuO3kII2erOG+iD3RXfqutdwzAxvMIQbVGAzHVGawcBMW+WJfgZ+uA==", "progress"=>{"title"=>"Hello", "date"=>"1st september 2016", "content"=>"bonjourbonjour", "main_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fede250ecb8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22001-1l0mkug.jpg>, @original_filename="12915103_10208497250246588_1486835977_o.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[main_image]\"; filename=\"12915103_10208497250246588_1486835977_o.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "progress_attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fede250eb78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22001-9k74to.jpg>, @original_filename="band.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[progress_attachments_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"band.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}}, "commit"=>"Create Progress"}

From: /Users/nelly/Desktop/ROR/leschner_guitars/app/controllers/progresses_controller.rb @ line 20 ProgressesController#create:

19: def create
 => 20:   binding.pry
    21:    @progress = Progress.new(progress_params)
    22:
    23:    respond_to do |format|
    24:      if @progress.save
    25:        params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
    26:           @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.create!(:image => a)
    27:        end
    28:
    29:        format.html { redirect_to progresses_path, notice: 'Progress was successfully created.' }
    30:      else
    31:        format.html { render action: 'new' }
    32:      end
    33:    end
    34:  end

[1] pry(#<ProgressesController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"KdZkIvo+lbmE8JPlMNOOFc2grNG6w9u4kuO3kII2erOG+iD3RXfqutdwzAxvMIQbVGAzHVGawcBMW+WJfgZ+uA==",
 "progress"=>
  {"title"=>"Hello",
   "date"=>"1st september 2016",
   "content"=>"bonjourbonjour",
   "main_image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fede250ecb8
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers=
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[main_image]\"; filename=\"12915103_10208497250246588_1486835977_o.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
     @original_filename="12915103_10208497250246588_1486835977_o.jpg",
     @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22001-1l0mkug.jpg>>,
   "progress_attachments_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"image"=>
        #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fede250eb78
         @content_type="image/jpeg",
         @headers=
          "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[progress_attachments_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"band.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
         @original_filename="band.jpg",
         @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22001-9k74to.jpg>>}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Progress",
 "controller"=>"progresses",
 "action"=>"create"}
[2] pry(#<ProgressesController>)>
```

and with changing like SteveTurczyn suggested:

```
Started POST "/progresses" for ::1 at 2016-09-02 01:49:14 +0200
Processing by ProgressesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XevIqKvA6UhcmipGb/zu8wJ3ItCwA5EBjldLQhwyXj7yx4x9FImWSw8ada8wH+T9m7e9HFtai3lQ7xlb4AJaNQ==", "progress"=>{"title"=>"This is a title", "date"=>"Today !", "content"=>"That's a short content", "main_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb00af89dc0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22410-13jb3ww.jpg>, @original_filename="band.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[main_image]\"; filename=\"band.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "progress_attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb00af89c80 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22410-6mze6c.jpg>, @original_filename="boss2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[progress_attachments_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"boss2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}}, "commit"=>"Create Progress"}

From: /Users/nelly/Desktop/ROR/leschner_guitars/app/controllers/progresses_controller.rb @ line 20 ProgressesController#create:

    19: def create
 => 20: binding.pry
    21:    @progress = Progress.new(progress_params)
    22:
    23:    respond_to do |format|
    24:      if params[:progress_attachments]
    25:        params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
    26:         @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.create!(:image => a)
    27:        end
    28:        format.html { redirect_to progresses_path, notice: 'Progress was successfully created.' }
    29:      else
    30:        format.html { render action: 'new' }
    31:      end
    32:    end
    33:  end

[1] pry(#<ProgressesController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XevIqKvA6UhcmipGb/zu8wJ3ItCwA5EBjldLQhwyXj7yx4x9FImWSw8ada8wH+T9m7e9HFtai3lQ7xlb4AJaNQ==",
 "progress"=>
  {"title"=>"This is a title",
   "date"=>"Today !",
   "content"=>"That's a short content",
   "main_image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb00af89dc0
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[main_image]\"; filename=\"band.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
     @original_filename="band.jpg",
     @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22410-13jb3ww.jpg>>,
   "progress_attachments_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"image"=>
        #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb00af89c80
         @content_type="image/jpeg",
         @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"progress[progress_attachments_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"boss2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
         @original_filename="boss2.jpg",
         @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160902-22410-6mze6c.jpg>>}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Progress",
 "controller"=>"progresses",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unless params[:progress_attachments].nil?
  params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
    @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.create!(:image => a)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a likely source of your error...

```
params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
```

If your params don't have a `:progress_attachments` key it will return nil, and doing `nil['image']` will give you exactly the error you're seeing.

You may want to inspect the params coming into the `create` method using `byebug` or `pry`.  If it's legitimate that no progress attachment needs to be present then you can wrap the each loop in `if params[:progess_attachments] ... end`

```
if params[:progress_attachments]
  params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
    @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.create!(:image => a)
  end
end
```

I'm not actually clear that this will be the finished solution as I'm not clear you'll have an array of images but inspection of the params should clarify that.

Comment: Hello Steve thanks for your answer, I  don't really know how to use pry or byebug could you explain me please ? I am newbie...

Comment: Install the gem pry in your Gemfile by inserting three lines... `group :development, test do; gem 'pry'; end` then do `bundle install` to install pry.  Then immediately after your `def create` line put in a line `binding.pry` and the next time the create method is called in development, the console will halt and you can type commands, like `params` to see what the params contain.  When you're ready to resume your application, type `exit` and the application will continue.

Comment: could you help me little more please. I updated the question with the pry :)