# Rails 5: Upload image in article form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I have article form which contains title and content. I want to add an file uploader in the form and I want this file uploader can upload an image or multiple images without the need to submit the article form.

I mean,when I create a new article and before I click **submit** the articel form, I would like to add a picture and I can upload pictures via file uploader and when I have selected a picture to be uploaded, the images will be sent directly to cloud storage and then the thumbnail will appear below the **browse** button. then when I **click** on the thumbnail, the image url will appear in the text area.

How to make file uploader like that? I've been browsing but didn't find a way, I just found how to display a thumbnail before upload to storage.

I use Carrierwave for image uploader and cloudinary for cloud storage.

and I have two table and a controller

Articles table

```
def change
   create_table :articles do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.text :content
     t.string :cover
end
```

Article_images table

```
def change
   create_table :article_images do |t|
     t.string :image
     t.integer :article_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

Article model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :cover, ImageUploader
    has_many :article_images, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_images, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    validates :title, :cover, :content, presence: true
    validates :title, uniqueness: true
end
```

Article_image model

```
class ArticleImage < ApplicationRecord
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
   belongs_to :article
end
```

Articles controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete_image
    images = ArticleImage.find(params[:id])
    article_id = images.article.id
    images.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to article_show_url(article_id), notice: 'Image was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content, :cover, :cover_cache, article_images_attributes: [:id, :image, :image_cache, :_destroy]) 
    end
end
```

**EDIT :**

here's my _form

```
    <div class="form-grup">
      <p>
      <%= f.label :title %>:<br/>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-grup">
      <p>
      <%= f.label :cover %>:<br/>
      <%= f.file_field :cover %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :cover_cache, :value => f.object.cover_cache %>
      </p>
    </div>


    <div class="form-grup">
      <p>
      <%= f.label :content %>:<br/>
      <%= f.cktext_area :content, :ckeditor => {:customConfig => asset_path('ckeditor/config.js')} %>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-grup">
      <p>
      <%= f.label :image, "Upload images:" %>
        <%= f.fields_for :article_images do |image| %>
          <%= render 'article_image_fields', f: image %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add image', f, :article_images %>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-grup actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
```

here's _article_image_fields

```
<% if f.object.image.present? %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= image_tag(f.object.image_url, size: "100x100") %> 
    </div>  <br/>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.file_field :image, type: :file %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache, :value => f.object.image_cache %> 
    </div>
    <div class="field"> 
        <%= link_to_remove_association "remove image", f %>
    </div>
<% else %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.file_field :image, type: :file %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache, :value => f.object.image_cache %> 
    </div>
    <div class="field"> 
        <%= link_to_remove_association "remove image", f %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

in my form when I create a new article, in the **file upload**
when I click **browse** and I've selected a picture, the picture is not directly uploaded to cloudinary but it took the wait submitted on a articles form. when I submit the article, the pictures will be uploaded

what I want is when I select a picture, the picture instantly uploaded to cloudinary **without** having to click on the **submit** button in my article form so that I can get url image to put in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave).

Specifically, notice that the `new` action sends both a `Article.new` and a `ArticleImage.new` and the use of `field_for`.

Your structure is good, but without looking at your form or elaboration on how far you've gotten, it's hard to understand what outcome you want exactly.