# Carrierwave multi-file upload Rails 5 not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails app, I wish for the users to be able to upload multiple files at once.

I am using the carrierwave gem

```
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
```

On the master branch which supposedly supports the `multiple: true`

found out in my internet searching desperation about the necessary addition of `optional: true` in my model for my attachment.

I'm using mysql so I can't use an array type in my database, but I've set up a `has_many`, `belongs_to` relationship between `Request` and `Request_Attachment` in my database.

my form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :request_attachments do |ra| %>
  <div class="row" id="uploader">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label class="btn btn-info"> Upload Files
        <%= ra.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: "request_attachments[file][]", :style => "display: none" %>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my controller

```
  @request = Request.new(request_params)

  if @request.save
    if params[:request][:request_attachments] 
      params[:request][:request_attachments]['file'].each do |f|
        @request_attachment = @request.request_attachments.create!(:file => f)
      end
    end
    flash[:success] = "Your request was submitted successfully, check your email for a confirmation message."
    redirect_to action: 'index', status: 303
  else
    render :new
  end

def request_params 
  params.require(:request).permit(:jobtitle, :requester, :status, request_attachments_attributes: [:id, :request_id, :file])
end
```

my models:

Request:

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :request_attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :request_attachments
end
```

Request_Attachments:

```
class RequestAttachment < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
  belongs_to :request, optional: true
end
```

I have tried variations of the form, like taking out the `name` portion.

When I remove the `multiple: true` portion, it will work perfectly, but it does not work with the `multiple` option.

I'm not quite sure where the issue may be, so any help would be great.

What is happening now is that the request gets saved, but

1. Only 1 request_attachment is created, and
2. The filename of the request_attachment is `nil`

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave

Comment: @AytanLeibowitz I've seen that code many times now, and it doesn't work for me, hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured it out.

I made a couple changes, which threw an error, and I looked closely at the Parameter Hash, and I noticed essentially it looked like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "request"=>
  {"jobtitle"=>"Testing, again and again, and again",
   "request_attachments_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"file"=>
        [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fee9df806b8
           @content_type="image/gif",
           @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"blah\"; filename=\"logo1.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n",
           @original_filename="logo1.gif",
           @tempfile=blah,
         #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fee9df80690
           @content_type="image\gif",
           @headers=
       "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"blah\"; filename=\"Blah.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n",
           @original_filename="Blah.gif",
           @tempfile=blahblah]}}
```

I noticed the `"0"=>` and thought "wait.... what is that doing there?....

So I removed the `name` section in my form, and changed my controller to look like this:

```
if @request.save
    params[:request][:request_attachments_attributes]["0"]['file'].each do |f|
      @request_attachment = @request.request_attachments.create!(:file => f)
    end
```

And that seemed to have worked.

Comment: you can also keep the `name` attribute in the form, and then the controller will just look like `params[:request_attachments]['file'].each do |f|` which is a bit simpler

Comment: The example that I posted demonstrated just that. Glad you figured it out!