# Rails4: likes total count: posts order with SQLite3 is OK but PostgreSQL not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

There is no problem with sqlite 3 but 'PG :: GroupingError: ERROR' appears in posgresql's environment.

I want to display posts with a lot of total by using paginate's gem in the order of total of like, but it is displayed without problem in sqlite 3

posts_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
  end

  def popular
    @posts = Post.joins(:likes).group(:post_id).order("count(*) desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
  end
```

However, in the postgres environment, 'PG :: GroupingError: ERROR: column' posts.id 'must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function' will be displayed and an error will be displayed.

likes table's column is

- id
- user_id
- post_id
- created_at
- updated_at

posts table's column is

- id
- title
- content
- picture
- category_id
- latitude
- longitude
- user_id
- address
- created_at
- updated_at

Looking at the answer, it seemed like it worked by modifying it, but another error appeared

```
def popular
    @posts = Post.joins(:likes).group(:id).order("count(*) desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
end
```

> SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "likes" ON "likes"."post_id"
>   = "posts"."id" GROUP BY "posts"."id"  ORDER BY count(*) desc LIMIT 18 OFFSET 0
>
> Rendered posts/popular.html.erb within layouts/application
>
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column
>   reference "id" is ambiguous
>
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, id AS id FROM "posts" INNER
>   JO...
>   : SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, id AS id FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "likes" > ON "likes"."post_id" = "posts"."id" GROUP BY "posts"."id"):

popular.html.erb

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col">
    <h2 class="mdl-typography--display-2 mdl-typography--font-thin">Popular posts</h2>
    <div class="mdl-grid">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="category category-shibuya"><%= link_to post.category.name, post.category.name %>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand" style="background: url('<%= post.post_attachments.first.picture %>') bottom center no-repeat #fff;">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"><%= post.title %></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <%= post.content.truncate(120, separator: '.')%>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a href="<%= post_path(post.id) %>" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple">
          View more
          <span class="mdl-button__ripple-container"><span class="mdl-ripple"></span></span></a>
        <span id="like-link<%= post.id %>" class="like_box">
          <%= render "likes/like_links", post: post %>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
</div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
</div>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "New posts") %>
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col">
    <h2 class="mdl-typography--display-2 mdl-typography--font-thin">New posts</h2>
    <div class="mdl-grid">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="category category-shibuya"><%= link_to post.category.name, post.category.name %>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand" style="background: url('<%= post.post_attachments.first.picture %>') bottom center no-repeat #fff;">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"><%= post.title %></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <%= post.content.truncate(120, separator: '.')%>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a href="<%= post_path(post.id) %>" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple">
          View more
          <span class="mdl-button__ripple-container"><span class="mdl-ripple"></span></span></a>
        <span id="like-link<%= post.id %>" class="like_box">
          <%= render "likes/like_links", post: post %>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
</div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
</div>
```

like.rb

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category 
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true  
  validates :content, presence: true 
  validates :category_id, presence: true 
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :post_attachments
  attr_accessor :post_attachment_attributes
  acts_as_commontable 
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments,allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  private

    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end
end
```

_like_links.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% if current_user.likes.find_by(post_id: post.id) %>
     <%= link_to (content_tag(:i, '', class: 'fa fa-heart')),unlike_path(post.id), method: :delete, remote: true %>
      <%=  post.likes.count %> Like
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to (content_tag(:i, '', class: 'fa fa-heart-o')),like_path(post.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
     <%=  post.likes.count %>  Like
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%=  post.likes.count %>  Like
<% end %>
```

It will be very helpful to tell me

thank you

Comment: Can you include show your associations for `Post` and `Like`?

Comment: And please provide your `likes/like_links` partial too.

Comment: hi Gerry. adding to "like_links.html.erb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PG :: GroupingError: ERROR: column' posts.id 'must appear in the GROUP
>   BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

You need to use `id` since you are calling `group` on `Post`, so there is no `post_id` available:

```
def popular
  @posts = Post.joins(:likes).group(:id).order("count(*) desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
end
```

> PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous

*likes* table has a column `id` causing the resulting SQL `SELECT COUNT() AS count_all, id AS id` to be ambiguous since `id` is on both tables to be joined (so `id` could be taken either from *likes* table or *posts* table).

To fix this i recommend deleting `id` column from *likes* table, since that table seems to be used only as a connection for a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Post` (more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)), so there is no need for `id`.

To do so, two things can be done:

1) Update *likes create migration* to avoid ids:

```
create_table :likes, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :post, index: true
  t.belongs_to :user, index: true
end
```

You will have to delete your table (i.e. rollback) and run the migration again.

2) Create a new migration file to delete `id` column:

```
def change
  remove_column :likes, :id
end
```

I prefer going with first option if you are still on development so you have less migrations to deal with, but if you are in production (or have data you don't want to lose) then go with the second option.

Comment: @projectsixth Great, glad to help. I would suggest that, whenever possible, use same DB in all your environments, that will avoid compatibility issues.

Comment: When attaching multiple photos using carrierwave, SQLite 3 was not able to reference this. I do not yet understand the best practices.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave

Comment: @projectsixth I haven't used carrierwave, so i'm not sure i can help here. I recommend you to ask another question so it can get more attention and better your odds of getting an answer.

Comment: Another error has appeared and it can not be displayed yet.　　’ActionView::Template::Error (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous　　LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, id AS id FROM "posts" INNER JO...’

Comment: @projectsixth Can you share your complete error and the line of code (or block of code) that generates it?

Comment: @projectsixth I tried to reproduce your error with no luck, it seems unrelated to the query. Can you provide your model associations?

Comment: thank you Gerry. update question adding post.rb and like.rb.

Comment: @projectsixth Great, still can't get to the error, can you include your partial `like/like_links`? Also, does the error shows the line where it was generated?

Comment: @projectsixth Still unable to reproduce the error, i created a repo with your code, but everything runs fine, [check it out](https://github.com/ggaona/project-sixth-posts). And you can view it on Heroku [here](https://project-sixth.herokuapp.com/) (Heroku runs pg database). Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Thank you very much. This behavior of heroku is my expectation.app/views/posts/popular.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_posts_popular_html_erb___3089418080647332627_69850437799500'

Comment: @projectsixth What "index" do you mean? Where did you add it?

Comment: sorry. I added it to the above question. posts_controller’s action and view(index.html.erb). The index is in the new posting order!

Comment: @projectsixth Found it. The problem is with your _likes_ table, you have an `id` when you don't need one and that is causing the error. So i recommend deleting that column (`id`), unless you have a specific use for it. You can either create a new migration for deleting it or, if you are still on development, you can modify your _create migration_ adding `id: false` (check the [migration](https://github.com/ggaona/project-sixth/blob/master/db/migrate/20170506115111_create_likes.rb) in the repo).

Comment: Hey @Gerry! It's amazing! I solved it safely! I could not imagine the problem like (ID) at all! You are really amazing!

Comment: hi @Gerry. (id) column 's delete is problem. Like record "destory" does not working.how can I destroy a record without an ID column in ActiveRecord? I will use "Like.delete_all(post_id: 'at mark' post.id, user_id: current_user)". but post.rb has "has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy". how can I? please help me.

Comment: @projectsixth What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to delete all liked posts from a specific user? or all users that liked a specific post?