# Why images doesn't save in cloudinary using Cloudinary/Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm uploading multiples `photos` and multiple `logos` in my model `Cover`. They are both correctly saved in DB but NOT in cloudinary.

As the configuration is the same for `logos` and `photos` I'll show you just once.

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave) to configurate multiple upload and [this](http://cloudinary.com/blog/ruby_on_rails_image_uploads_with_carrierwave_and_cloudinary) for cloudinary config.

**cover.rb**

```
class Cover < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cover_attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cover_attachments
end
```

**cover_attachment.rb**

```
class CoverAttachment < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
  belongs_to :cover
end
```

**photo_uploader.rb**

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  process convert: 'png'
  process tags: ['cover_photo']

  version :standard do
    process resize_to_fill: [100, 150, :north]
  end

  version :thumbnail do
    resize_to_fit(50, 50)
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

**_form.html.slim**

```
= simple_form_for [current_user, @book, @cover], html: { multipart: true } do |f|

   = f.label :photo, 'photos'
   = f.file_field :photo, multiple: true, name: "cover_attachments[photo][]"

 ...
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "cover_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "photo"
    t.string   "logo"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "cover_id"
  end

  create_table "cover_type_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "cover_id"
    t.string   "cover_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["cover_id"], name: "index_cover_type_users_on_cover_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "covers", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
  end
```

**covers_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    if @cover.save
       params[:cover_attachments]['photo'].each do |a|
         @cover_attachment = @cover.cover_attachments.create!(photo: a)
       end
    ...
    end
 end
```

**terminal output**

```
Processing by CoversController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VnBZ7iysnNsl8oVbBjqvPd8ZbsMQrn0JQCOtg5kSHnjovVOhFPBcyu1xzXCytVkXrHH1b+TcpbnCire7XB9hSg==", "cover"=>{"design_tags"=>"kjh", "client_wishes"=>"kj", "format"=>"12X24", "isbn"=>"", "selling_price"=>"", "book_id"=>"210"}, "cover_attachments"=>{"photo"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8698ce73b0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0w/pznf2h6j0q9gqcbcthg1kgm40000gn/T/RackMultipart20170816-9346-1qrdd6j.jpg>, @original_filename="andrew-neel-266219.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cover_attachments[photo][]\"; filename=\"andrew-neel-266219.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}, "commit"=>"poursuivre", "user_id"=>"112", "book_id"=>"210", "id"=>"188"}

 ....

 SQL (6.8ms)  INSERT INTO "cover_attachments" ("photo", "created_at", "updated_at", "cover_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["photo", "j43shp8bkjfg0wsc8y3r.png"], ["created_at", 2017-08-16 10:12:58 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-08-16 10:12:58 UTC], ["cover_id", 188]]
```

Comment: you upload them to local filesystem, not to cloudinary

Comment: Do I just need to remove `def store_dir` ?

Comment: yes. and put a `public_id` method inside uploader. https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/3260c82263b6d2c30ab63184962380a0

Comment: I get this `undefined method title for #<CoverAttachment:0x007fdd13a39038>`. Is it the same if I do `model.class.name.parameterize` instead of `model.title.parametize` ?

Comment: It works ! Thank you ! :)

Comment: i forget to add, i have title method/property defined for all models. pick whatever you want.