# Can a CarrierWave uploader be used to upload files from different directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

I am looking for a particular workflow from CarrierWave that I haven't been able to find an example of. I want to allow the user to select files from multiple directory locations to upload.

The closest example of this I can find is described here: [Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave). The difference between this functionality and what I want is rather than allowing a user to select multiple files from the same directory, I would like them to be able to select a file then re-open the file upload dialog and select another file from a separate directory. The [CarrierWave documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads) similarly only mentions multiple uploads from the same directory. Is this possible with CarrierWave?

Possible solution: Based on what I found in [this post](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast), it looks like the `process`method can be used to run code immediately when the file is uploaded. Would it be appropriate to use this method to save the file or add it to an array of files to be saved?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Have you find a solution ?

Comment: This is the best tutorial I've found that addresses my use case: https://richonrails.com/articles/multiple-file-uploads-with-dropzone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is not of CarrierWare. It's restriction of HTML and browsers.

You need to use a javascript library to select multiple files. Like this https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ or http://www.dropzonejs.com/