# Rails 5.1.2 Wicked Gem and Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms, wicked-gem, ruby-on-rails-5

**Ruby:** 2.4.0
**Rails:** 5.1.2

---

Hey Guys,
I'm not completely new to Rails but definitely not an expert.

What I'm trying to do is to create a wicked wizard with nested attributes.

I already searched via Google, GitHub and StackOverflow but haven't found anything except of [this](http://Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749770/) and [that](http://Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339086/).

Both is not working.
What I have is the following:

***-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ EDIT !!!-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_***

The problem was, that i havent defined an create action -.-'
i had to modify some variable names as well. rails is a bit confusing with the pluralization sometimes in my opinion. luckily was was finally able to do this super simple stuff :D

---

### **Models**

user.rb (from the devise gem)

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_one :accountinfo
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :accountinfo, update_only: true

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    validates_presence_of :password, :email, :accounttype

end
```

#### account_information.rb

#### edit: accountinfo.rb

The model i want to store the user information in to not overload my user table (everything well sorted)

```
class AccountInformation < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :user

end
```

I have used wicked a couple of times and it always works but only if i store all the information in the user model... which i dont want to do this time because of a better structure and stuff.

---

### **Controller**

### users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def create
        @user = User.create( user_params )
    end

    def show

        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        if user_signed_in?
            render 'show'

        else
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end


    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :accounttype, :accountinfo, accountinfos_attributes:[:user_id, :competence])
    end
end
```

### **user_steps_controller**

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :welcome

before_action :authenticate_user!


def show
        @user = current_user
        render_wizard
end

def create
        @accountinfo = @user.accountinfo.create(user_params)
end

def update  
        @user = current_user
        @user.update(user_params)

        render_wizard @user
end


private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:accountinfo,accountinfo_attributes:[:id, :competence])
end

private
def redirect_to_finish_wizard_path
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Danke für deine Zeit!"
end

   end


   private
   def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:accounttype, 
       account_information_attributes:[:id, :competence])
   end

   private
   def redirect_to_finish_wizard_path
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Danke für deine Zeit!"
   end

   end
```

---

### **Views**

welcome.html.erb

```
       <%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>    
                <%= f.fields_for(:accountinfo) do |builder| %>
                    <div class="m-wizard__choose2 m-wizard__choose2--border-right">
                       <label>   
                            <%= builder.radio_button :competence, 1, class: "input-hidden" %>
                             <i class="icon-people-male h1"></i>
                            <p class="h6 m-text--bold">Designer</p>
                        </label> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="m-wizard__choose2">
                        <label>   
                            <%= builder.radio_button :competence, 2, class: "input-hidden" %>
                             <i class="icon-people h1"></i>
                            <p class="h6 m-text--bold">Texter</p>
                        </label>                  
                    </div>
                <% end %>

                <div class="m-text--center">
                    <%= f.submit "Weiter", class: "m-button" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

---

Maybe you already found something ...

I want my user to come to the welcome.html.erb after the registration.

devise is working well, the redirection to the wicked controller as well. wicked does work properly as always, the routes are also set up correctly but this time I want my information of "*competence*" to be stored into the associated table of account_information.

After I press the "Weiter" ("continue" in German) button, nothing happens but the site re-renders. This is what my console outputs:

> Processing by UserStepsController#update as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"uYRJyCeBGyyDcWUtIj62fmT9oMpTnUQ3p+CSi3n8tSKKLguB1j/CPZaeuZCcmpCoBjJDKY6yz7/Z2wXfAO7YBg==",
>   "user"=>{"account_information_attributes"=>{"competence"=>"1"}},
>   "commit"=>"Weiter", "id"=>"welcome"}   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT 
>   "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id"
>   ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]    (0.0ms)  begin transaction 
>   AccountInformation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "account_informations".* FROM
>   "account_informations" WHERE "account_informations"."user_id" = ?
>   LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]    (0.1ms)  rollback
>   transaction    (0.0ms)  begin transaction    (0.0ms)  rollback
>   transaction

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t56Zb.png that is the link to the console output

Answer (score 0):

According to Wicket doc:

```
class AfterSignupController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :confirm_password, :confirm_profile, :find_friends

  def show
    @user = current_user
    case step
    when :find_friends
      @friends = @user.find_friends
    end
    render_wizard
  end
end
```

You should have somewhere a `case step` in your controller, which I'm not seeing in your current code.

Looks like a redirection issue

Comment: Thank you for you help. i added the case step stuff to my controller but the redirection still not seem to work and i cant figure out why. as well i have to do " @account_information = @user.build_account_information" in my steps controller, if i remove the build_ the form wont display

Comment: add sone debug in your code (old school `logger.debug MESSAGE` to check what's going on in your app.

Comment: i did not get any success with it :S i just cant figure out what is blocking my code. maybe its the route? do i have to do std like 
`resources :user do
     resources :account_information
end` in my routes, or is it something like `d.fields_for :account_information_attributes` in my nested form?

Comment: Does not seem to be connected to the fields as they have nothing to do with routing. Based on the information you provided this looks like a routing issue. `routes.rb` or your controller may be overriding the expected behavior

Comment: i have no clue :/ i just cant figure out whats going wrong. my routes.rb had `resources :account_information` but even with removing it, there is no benefit.

Comment: Try adding logger.debug message to track where you're going. Also use your browser to assist and point to the pages urls and compare what you are experiencing with what you really have.

Comment: Placing few messages in your controller will help to understand the flow and what is wrong

Comment: i have found the problem. i will update my post to show you what was wrong ! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. the problem was the missing create action and some other stuff. i edited the post, so you can read ist

Comment: nevermind ... stuff just dont work anymore.. i dont understand rails sometimes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175850/rails-fields-for-form-not-showing-up-nested-form this made the trick